# Match the values row by row of two columns of a data frame

Tags: r, matching

I have a data frame something like this:

```
| Employee | Expense_Type    | Default_Expense | Amount |   |
|----------|-----------------|-----------------|--------|---|
| John     | Airfare         | Airfare         | 1000   |   |
| David    | Hotel_Tax       | Hotel           | 50     |   |
| Nancy    | Miscellaneous   | Undefined       | 500    |   |
| Mike     | Individual_Meal | Individual_Meal | 75     |   |
| Jenny    | Airline_tax     | Airfare         | 125    |   |
```

I want to compare the 'Expense_Type' and 'Default_Expense' columns row by row and generate a new column to paste the values which did not match. For example, from the above table, we can see that row no 2, 3 and 5 do not match as hotel_tax is different than hotel, miscellaneous is different than undefined and airline_tax is different than airfare.

I tried looking into different problems mentioned where I came across the below solution to use:
`df2$Expense_Type[!(df2$Expense_Type %in% df2$Default_Expense)]`
but this did not seem to work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `%in%` operator does not compare each row. Use the `==` operator do to this. This will convert each row to a boolean which you can use to filter :-)

```
df2[df2$Expense_Type == df2$Default_Expense, ]
```

For the value:

```
df$newcol <- ifelse(df2$Expense_Type == df2$Default_Expense, "Correct", "Wrong")
```

Comment: You´re welcome. If you like my solution, accepting the answer is highly appreceated :-)

Comment: I did that but I get a message :"Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score"

Comment: @hk2, you can click the green arrow next to it to accept it. It will give you that notice if you try to upvote it :).

Comment: like Andrew said ;-)